# is_page() is not executed

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am making infinite scroll page. I created a page template where posts of certain category are loaded. Everything works fine with a single page and single category.

But I have three pages with this page template and each page should load articles from a specific category. I am using the `is_page()` if elseif block to determine on which page visitor is. But `is_page()` is not executed.

Here is the loop:

```
$cat = '';
if(is_page(703)){
    $cat = 4;
} elseif (is_page(706)) {
    $cat = 21;
}
    $args = array(
        'cat' => $cat,
        'paged' => $paged
        );
    $infinite_news_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $infinite_news_query -> have_posts() ) : while ( $infinite_news_query -> have_posts() ) : $infinite_news_query -> the_post(); 
 <?php endwhile; ?>

 <?php else : ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

This code displays all the posts, regardless of category, and `$cat` is empty inside the loop.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page
`Cannot Be Used Inside The Loop.
Due to certain global variables being overwritten during The Loop is_page() will not work. In order to use it after The Loop you must call wp_reset_query() after The Loop.`

Comment: He is calling is_page before the loop is initiated, or is there something I do not get?

Comment: @razhial `is_page()` is before the loop. it is simply there to assign different value to the `$cat` variable which is used in query arguments.

Comment: ok im sorry, got a bit confused there myself ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
$cat = '';
if(is_page(703)){
    $cat = 4;
} elseif (is_page(706)) {
    $cat = 21;
}
```

to:

```
if(is_page('703')){
    $cat = 4;
} else { if(is_page('706')) {
    $cat = 21;
}
```

Also removing `$cat = '';`

Comment: I can't work it out either, why your solution works. What are we getting wrong? After all, if the current page is id-ed 703 or 706, the empty variable gets changed, doesn't it?

Comment: There is no need to set the $cat as empty / false. I found using elseif instead of just else, and then an if statement within the else makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it like this, at first you have the variable `$cat` set to empty value, respectively, to false , zero or 0.

Then you set a loop, with only two states, leaving out a default value.
So, what is going to happen, when your page ID is changed?

You get all the posts displayed.

In other words, I do not see anything bad in the code. I would rather recommend you to use `is_page('slug')` than with `id`.

Comment: result is the same if I use slug instead of ID. Each state is assigning different value to the `$cat`... or at least it should, but it is not.